# Microsoft Chart stacked columns grouped with non-stacked

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I was hoping to display data for 4 groups.  Each group has 1 stacked column, and 1 non-stacked.  Here's a mockup of what I'm after:

[image: What i'm trying to do]

Getting four groups is easy, this gives me what I want:

```
Series series = chart.Series.Add("Budget");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
series.Name = "Budget";
series.Points.Add(55);
series.Points.Add(10);
series.Points.Add(50);
series.Points.Add(50);

series  = chart.Series.Add("Actual");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
series.Name = "Actual";
series.Points.Add(80);
series.Points.Add(90);
series.Points.Add(10);
series.Points.Add(10);
```

[image: the easy graph]

Now I want to make the yellow bars stacked bars.  I've experimened with adding 3 series; ChartType = Column, StackedColumn, StackedColumn.  But the stacked columns appear infront of the non-stacked one.

[image: what i'm getting]

Is what I'm attempting possible?

Comment: I have same need. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Under the Series Invoke the CustomPropertiesMethod and assign the groups different StackedGroupNames for example if you want Series 1 and 2 to stack but want series 3 to be beside

`Series1.CustomProperties = "StackedGroupName=Group1";
Series2.CustomProperties = "StackedGroupName=Group1";
Series3.CustomProperties = "StackedGroupName=Group2";`

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but the series are shown in the same order as they're added.

Comment: they are appearing in the order they were added.  but when i combine Column & StackedColumn they appear overlapping, not beside each other.

Comment: are you setting the charttype before adding the series to the chartarea or after ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I approached it was to phony up the X-axis data so it was offset on either side of the 'real' points, then use custom labels.  I don't have easily pasted. tested code, but I think it goes something like this:

```
double pointWidth = 0.375;
double pointOffset = pointWidth * 0.5;
// Add first series - column
_Chart.Add("Series1");
_Chart.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
_Chart.Series["Series1"]["PointWidth"] = pointWidth.ToString();
for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
{
  _Chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(ii - pointOffset, YourYValueHere);
}
// Add second series - stacked column
_Chart.Add("Series2");
_Chart.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
_Chart.Series["Series2"]["PointWidth"] = pointWidth.ToString();
for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
{
  _Chart.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(ii + pointOffset, YourYValueHere);
}
// Add thrid series - stacked column
_Chart.Add("Series3");
_Chart.Series["Series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
_Chart.Series["Series3"]["PointWidth"] = pointWidth.ToString();
for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
{
  _Chart.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(ii + pointOffset, YourYValueHere);
    _Chart.ChartAreas["Area1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(
     ii - 0.5, ii + 0.5, ii);
}
_Chart.ChartAreas["Area1"].AxisX.Minimum = -0.5;
_Chart.ChartAreas["Area1"].AxisX.Maximum =
              _Chart.Series["Series3"].Points.Count - 0.5;
_Chart.ChartAreas["Area1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
_Chart.ChartAreas["Area1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```

If that StackedGroupName thing works, it would be much simpler, though.  I'm going to try it.

Comment: Could not get StackedGroupName to work in .NET framework 3.5.