# Both stacked and unstacked columns in ASP.NET MS Charting

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, mschart

I have 4 pieces of data being shown: Base Sales, Upsells, Cancellations, No Sales

I want Base Sales & Upsells in a stacked column and Cancellations & No Sales in their own unstacked columns.

This is how I am creating my series:

```
    //--- set base package series
    Series BasePackageSeries = new Series("BasePackageSeries");
    BasePackageSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    BasePackageSeries.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#146c00"); //--- dark green

    //--- set upsell package series
    Series UpsellPackageSeries = new Series("UpsellPackageSeries");
    UpsellPackageSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    UpsellPackageSeries.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#1fa700"); //--- lighter green

    //--- set civ series
    Series CIVSeries = new Series("CIV");
    CIVSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    CIVSeries.Color = Color.Gold;

    //--- set no sales series
    Series NSSeries = new Series("No Sales");
    NSSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    NSSeries.Color = Color.Red;
```

When they are added, the first 3 appear stacked and No Sales is by itself (probably because it's so large). I want the first 2 stacked and the last 2 by themselves. Any advice on how to achieve what I want?

I manually generate the data points via a loop. If you need to see that, let me know.

Comment: I have same need. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, ended up doing something different with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979219/microsoft-chart-stacked-columns-grouped-with-non-stacked (which also doesn't have an answer)